# modify specific node with xmllint or other solution?

Tags: xml, shell, aix, xmllint

I have an xml file  like this :

```
<!-- environnement totoserver -->
<envs>
 <env>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>toto</name>
  <ip_server>1.1.1.1</ip_server>
  <state>on</state>
 </env>
 <env>
  <id>2</id> [...]
 </env>

  <!-- environnement tata serveur -->
  <env>[...]
  </env>
  [...]
</envs>
```

In order to find the value of specific node, I use xmllint. 
With this, I try to modify the state value of "toto" environment. 
But, i don't find the correct command.

So, is anyone knows the command line to do that ?

If it's not possible, how I can do that ? If possible, no installation of package.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '/envs/env/state[../name="toto"]' -v "$newvalue" file.xml
```

If you want to save the file in-place:

```
xmlstarlet ed --in-place -u ...
```

Comment: thanks for you answer but I don't have xmlstarlet in the server.

Comment: In modern versions of the package the command appears to go by the name of plain `xml` instead of `xmlstarlet`. Otherwise, very helpful.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: the original command name was always `xml` AFAIK, but debian-derivatives rename it to `xmlstarlet`.